# Check if part of lines match with lines in dataset

Tags: python, dataset, match

I have a database which consists of a line with car brands, models and a lot of rubbish and some other, clean information. I also have a database with most of the car brands and models, and I want to check if these brands and models appear in the dirty lines and replace them with the brand and model.

I am more or less new to Python, so it would be nice to receive some support.

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the two files Dirty and Clean.  You could have a loop that indexes through Dirty and then another loop within that loop that indexes through clean to see if the line you are searching for exists.

If the line does exist in Clean write it out into a new file called NEWDATABASE if not write what already exists in Dirty.

If you are more specific with your question and provide what the lines look like, I could help more.

Comment: Thanks. The lines look like "Volkswagen Golf Plus 1.2 TSI 105 PK DSG AUTOMAAT MATCH CLIMA / CRUISE / PDC *clean data*", I want "Volkswagen Golf Plus *clean data*". It's quite a large file, more than 500 000 lines.

Comment: I am still confused at what it is you are asking.  Can you be super specific in your question and give detailed examples?

Comment: I have a database with over 500 000 dirty lines like "Volkswagen Golf Plus 1.2 TSI 105 PK DSG AUTOMAAT MATCH CLIMA / CRUISE / PDC", then a tab, then some clean data. Besides, I have a dataset with clean lines, like "Volkswagen Golf Plus". I want to replace the dirty line with the clean one, and keep the clean data after the tab.